# Laravel Echo and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js

When I'm importing Echo in Vue.js' resouces/assets/js/bootstrap.js one of my components throws an error

> Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: $ is not a function"

Everything works fine without Echo. What can I do to solve the problem?

1. [Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylT8H.jpg)
2. [Bootstrap.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljQ9n.jpg)
3. [DateRangePicker.vue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibbaU.jpg)

Comment: add code to your answer

Comment: Aren't you missing jQuery? `import $ from 'jquery';` ?

Comment: The [laravel boilerplate bootsrap.js](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js#L11) includes jQuery as a `window.$` global. Is this like still in your bootstrap.js ?

Comment: @apokryfos, yes. You can see it in my second screenshot.

Comment: a) Screenshots of code should not be acceptable b) does it throw an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upd: Solved by adding jquery to laravel-mix plugins array

> new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
>         $: "jquery",
>         jQuery: "jquery",
>         "window.jQuery": "jquery"
>       })